# syntax of a line of code from matlab to python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab, numpy, opencv

I have this line of code over here in Matlab:

```
DCT_matrix = orig_img(row: row + blocksize-1, col: col + blocksize-1);
```

I'd like to translate it in python but I can't seem to figure out the function of the colon ":" inside the matrix. can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Isn't thst just slice notation? So in Python you would do literally the same except using square brackets instead of parentheses. Oh, and leave out the `-1` at the right end of each slice

Comment: @PaulPanzer yes, this is exactly what it is thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would depend on what you're using for `orig_img` in python. If you are using a list of lists, you can use list-indexing. If you are using a numpy array/matrix that supports very similar indexing too.

```
In []: a = list(range(10))

In []: a
Out[]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In []: a[3:4]
Out[]: [3]

In []: a[3:]
Out[]: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In []: a[3:7]
Out[]: [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here's numpy:

```
In []: an = np.array(a)

In []: an[3:7]
Out[]: array([3, 4, 5, 6])
```

A list cannot have 2 dimensions so you would do something like `a[ind1][ind2]` where you first request for index1 and then index2 as it is a list in a list. For numpy arrays you do the same. For numpy matrices it is very similar to matlab:

```
In []: mat = np.random.rand(20,20)

In []: mat[3:6, 5:8]
Out[]:
array([[0.67252461, 0.96330823, 0.96040509],
       [0.59030486, 0.33355469, 0.45762365],
       [0.19180032, 0.03105064, 0.63050375]])
```

Note: Matlab has indices starting from 1 to `length of array`. Python has them starting from 0 to `length of array - 1`.